# Derivative of Function of Unitary matrices

Tags: differentiation, calculus, lattice-model, lattice-gauge-theory

I need some help in understanding derivative of function of matrices, Unitary matrices in my case.
I am studying lattice-qcd, there i need to take derivative of Wilson gauge action, $S[U]$ w.r.t link $U$.
\begin{equation}
S[U] \equiv \sum_x\sum_{\mu<\nu} Tr(U_{\mu\nu}(x))
\end{equation}
here,
$$U_{\mu\nu} = U_\mu(x)U_\nu(x+\mu)U_{\mu}^\dagger(x+\nu)U_{\nu}^\dagger(x)$$
Now, I have to compute $-\frac{\partial S[U]}{\partial U}$. I have come across a formula for derivative on unitary group.[1]
$$\frac{\partial S[U]}{\partial U} = \sum_a\lambda_a\frac{\partial S[e^{i\alpha\lambda_a} U]}{\partial \alpha}\Big\rvert_{\alpha\rightarrow0}$$
$\lambda_a$ are the generators of $SU(N)$ group.

I am able to make sense of this formula like, $e^{i\alpha\lambda_a}$ are used to generate small displacements in directions of generators (basis) $\lambda_a$ and then we take limit $\alpha\rightarrow0$. This is exactly like the definition of derivative. But I don't know how to arrive at this.

And I am not able to use this compute the derivative I need to compute viz. $-\frac{\partial S[U]}{\partial U}$.
Here is my attempt to compute the derivative.
\begin{align}
  \frac{\partial S[e^{i\alpha\lambda_a U}]}{\partial \alpha}\Big\rvert_{\alpha\rightarrow0} &= \sum_x\sum_{\mu\lt\nu}\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha}Tr\left(e^{i\alpha\lambda_a}U_{\mu}(x)e^{i\alpha\lambda_a}U_{\nu}(x+\mu)U^{\dagger}_{\mu}(x+\nu)(e^{i\alpha\lambda_a})^{\dagger}U^{\dagger}_{\nu}(x)(e^{i\alpha\lambda_a})^{\dagger}\right)\Bigr\rvert_{\alpha=0}\\
  &= \sum_x\sum_{\mu\lt\nu}\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha}Tr\left({U_{\mu}(x)e^{i\alpha\lambda_a}U_{\nu}(x+\mu)U^{\dagger}_{\mu}(x+\nu)(e^{i\alpha\lambda_a})^{\dagger)}U^{\dagger}_{\nu}(x)}\right)\Bigr\rvert_{\alpha=0} \\
  &= i\sum_x\sum_{\mu\lt\nu}\left[Tr\left({U_{\mu}(x)\lambda_a U_{\nu}(x+\mu)U^{\dagger}_{\mu}(x+\nu)U^{\dagger}_{\nu}(x)}\right) + Tr\left(U_{\mu}(x)U_{\nu}(x+\mu)U^{\dagger}_{\mu}(x+\nu)\lambda_a U^{\dagger}_{\nu}(x)\right) \right]
 \end{align}
I am quite sure that I have made a mistake somewhere. Can someone help in pointing out where i am going wrong, Or is there some other way to evaluate this derivative.\

References.
[1] eq. (2.6) in https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.08778